# Filtering an array of records in coffeescript to return all records with age > 50

Tags: arrays, filter, coffeescript, records

Given this sort of data set

```
records = [
  {id: 1, name: "John Smith", age: 49},
  {id: 2, name: "Jane Brown", age: 45},
  {id: 3, name: "Tim Jones",  age: 60},
  {id: 4, name: "Blake Owen", age: 78}    
]
```

How do I filter the records to return a reduced array that is just over the age of 50.

Say the return array is

```
over50s = // something
```

I've looked at lots of similar code but it's just quite coming together for me.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this sample script? The result `over50s` is retrieved using `filter()`.

#### Sample script :

```
records = [
  {id: 1, name: "John Smith", age: 49},
  {id: 2, name: "Jane Brown", age: 45},
  {id: 3, name: "Tim Jones",  age: 60},
  {id: 4, name: "Blake Owen", age: 78}
]
over50s = records.filter (e) -> e.age >= 50
```

#### Result :

```
[
    { id: 3, name: 'Tim Jones',  age: 60 },
    { id: 4, name: 'Blake Owen', age: 78 }
]
```

If I misunderstand your question, please tell me. I would like to modify.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is perfect, but I wanted to add the "Coffeescript way" using [comprehensions](http://coffeescript.org/#loops):

```
 over50s = (record for record in records when record.age > 50)
```

### Explanation :

```
for record in records
  console.log(record)
# This would loop over the records array, 
#   and each item in the array will be accessible 
#   inside the loop as `record`

console.log(record) for record in records
# This is the single line version of the above

console.log(record) for record in records when record.age > 50
# now we would only log those records which are over 50

over50s = (record for record in records when record.age > 50)
# Instead of logging the item, we can return it, and as coffeescript
#   implicitly returns from all blocks, including comprehensions, the 
#   output would be the filtered array
# It's shorthand for:
    
over50s = for record in records
  continue unless record.age > 50
  record

# This long hand is better for complex filtering conditions. You can
#   just keep on adding `continue if ...` lines for every condition
# Impressively, instead of ending up with `null` or `undefined` values
#   in the filtered array, those values which are skipped by `continue`
#   are completely removed from the filtered array, so it will be shorter.
```

Comment: Thank you. I saw this style when searching originally.. how do I read the "record for record in" part?   eg do you happen to know what that first "record" achieves?  thanks

Comment: If you're going to use a one-liner, you have to be careful with your parentheses: `over50s = (record for record in records when record.age > 50)`. Otherwise you're just saying `over50s = record` for each `record`.

Comment: @muistooshort Good catch, I tested in the coffee shell, but I only saw the output of the comprehension, the `over50s` var was never set